# User script for CTAN Package and TeXDoc.net buttons

Tags: support, editing, user-interface, user-script

I often like to link to the corresponding [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/) page if I mention packages in my posts. I always wished there would be a button which does this for me.
I now hacked some Greasemonkey user script together which adds one to the button bar on top of the input field. On request I added a second button for the package manuals on http://texdoc.net/.

Simply type the package name, mark it with the mouse and press the `CTAN` or `DOC` buttons on top. Many thanks goes to Paulo Cereda for designing the icons.

[image: CTAN before]

[image: CTAN after]

[image: TeXDoc Before]

[image: TeXDoc after]

---

For Firefox this needs [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) to be installed. There are also alternatives for other browsers, but I can't say if they work.

Note that this does not work in cases were the edit window is not displayed from the start, i.e. when you answer your own question or provide a second answer. Also it might not work if you reload a page. In this case reload it again by selecting the URL in the browser location bar and hit enter.

Also the buttons do not update the preview window. You need to type some text before it is updated.

---

[image: View code] [image: Direct install]

Comment: Seems to work fine in Opera. Thanks!

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Yes, Opera 8 and above should have support for user scripts.

Comment: @Jake: Paulo already asked me that in the chat room. I can do this.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Excellent!

Comment: @Jake: See my update.

Comment: All works nicely in Chrome. Thanks for this!

Comment: Awesome! Awesome! Awesome! `:)`

Comment: Really useful; thank you. I must confess that I still write most of the URLs manually (old habits die hard), but gradually I am starting to use the script.

Comment: How does one install this in, say, Chrome? (Great work, btw.)

Comment: @JohnWickerson: You may need tampermonkey extension for chrome.

Comment: Sadly the links don't work at the moment...

Comment: @MartinScharrer Sounds like a really useful thing. Is this script still available somewhere?