# Useful StackApps and other User Scripts for TeX.SX

Tags: discussion, scripts

Some people might not know it, but on https://stackapps.com/ there are several applications / user scripts available which makes certain tasks easier for moderators and other users which often post helpful comments.

I like to point out some of them here. Feel free to post other ones as answer posts.

These user scripts require the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) extension for Firefox. Modern versions of Opera and Chrome should also support them directly. After installing the extension, then user scripts can be installed by clicking on the *Install* link which should pop up a installation dialog.

---

### [Copy Question Link Markdown - Making it easier to copy links to questions!](https://stackapps.com/a/3318/10230)

Adds a 'copy' link below questions and answers in the `[title](url)` form required for formatted links in comments. This is much better than posting the URL only or a "this" or "here" link.

[image]

---

### [SE Comment Link Helper](https://stackapps.com/q/2378/10230)

When submitting a comment, this script will turn all bare URLs to SE posts into the `[title](url)` form by looking up the title using the official API. It can lead to a short delay when submitting the comment. I use this sometimes to turn single URLs in comments of other users into the full form.

---

### [Easy way to copy code block?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/easy-way-to-copy-code-block/891#891)

See dedicated post.

---

### [User script for CTAN Package and TeXDoc.net buttons](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/user-script-for-ctan-package-and-texdoc-net-buttons)

See dedicated post

Comment: The SE Comment Link Helper (formerly _Comment Link AutoPrettifier_) has improved a lot in the past few months; I was writing back and forth with the maintainer a number of times and I’d say it now works pretty much flawlessly.

Comment: Related question on [metase]: [What third-party tools are there for the trilogy websites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5188)

Answer (score 26):

### [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/10230)

This user script adds an 'auto' link below "Add Comment":

[image]

It opens the following configurable dialog with some pre-defined comments:

[image]

This is very useful for the frequent used [text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks).
If the user is new a welcome message is automatically added. However, this message is currently hard-code. I modified my local copy of the script to use our "Welcome to TeX.SX" message. I should upload this version somewhere, too.

It is possible to export and import messages in markdown format.
Here my pre-defined comments. Use the 'import/export' link on the bottom to import them.

```
###MWE required
Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

###Follow-up question posted as an answer
Answer posts are intended for solutions to the original question. If you have a similar question which is not answered here, please post it as a fresh one using the "Ask Question" link above. [Follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please also include a link to this question to provide the background.

###"Thank you" answers
Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank [user] by upvoting [his/her] answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.

###Code blocks and inline code
A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

###Image inclusion How-To
Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.


###Migrated Question
Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.
```

---

The script now supports also a custom welcome message. To change it click on "Welcome" at the lower right. The normal welcome message for new users is:

```
[Welcome to TeX.sx!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)
```

Note the trailing space which is required.

Comment: Any chance of getting an official and standard json script to link with the [building blocks](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) answers to just consume it using this app? 

I like it, but one needs to copy the answers from machine to machine.

Answer (score 4):

As I already wrote in [my answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2410/9237) to [RSS feed for New questions?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/rss-feed-for-new-questions):

## [Stack2RSS - A JSON to RSS Conversion Service](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source)

It’s much better than the default RSS feed: More options are possible with finer filtering. You get more information on an own website: [Stack2RSS - Creating RSS Feeds from API Routes!](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/).

See another usage example in [my answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3338/9237) to [how to start looking at the question archive starting at a known place in the middle?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/how-to-start-looking-at-the-question-archive-starting-at-a-known-place-in-the-mi)

Answer (score 4):

### Select code

To copy code to the clipboard, one has to select it, which is especially cumbersome if one has to scroll up or down while selecting.

I ["found"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6183/4736) a usefull script on https://stackapps.com/questions , which exactly provides a "Select" button, if the mouse is on a code field: https://stackapps.com/questions/2553/select-code-block-buttons-script

For the use within Firefox, one has to install the Greasemonkey addon and to import the script there as an userscript. For security concerns (a script that copies *any* code to the clipboard seems risky), I restricted the script to tex.stackexchange.com/* .

**Warning: Installing makes procrastination of your work even easier.**

Comment: Could you help me? I've tried to install this script but never worked to me. Now I've followed your instructions: Install Greasemonkey and copied (I didn't know how to import it) the code as a new userscript. But when I go to TX.SX I don't see any new button before a code window neither a new option in mouse buttons. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

## [New Q! is a Google Chrome browser extension](https://stackapps.com/q/587)

that notifies you whenever:

- Someone asks a question that interests you
- Someone comments on your question
- Someone comments on your answer
- You receive a Careers   message
- You receive a chat message

Whenever these things happen you   receive a desktop notification like the ones shown above. This means   no more refreshing the page of your favorite SE sites to look for
questions to answer or new inbox notifications. You just wait until
you are notified and then click the notification and a new tab opens
for you.

[image]

These are quoted from the [original post](https://stackapps.com/q/587).

Answer (score 2):

## [stacknotify google chrome extension](https://stackapps.com/q/2356)

Your Stack Overflow notification inbox, right into your browser's toolbar.

- it checks for new notifications every minute
- shows a notification badge for new items
- supports all Stack Exchange websites

[image]

These are quoted from the [original post](https://stackapps.com/q/2356).

Answer (score 1):

## [Moderator links](https://stackapps.com/q/3832)

Adds some extra links to posts and userpages for convenience

For a userpage, all links from the "info" mod menu, except "privileges" is displayed along in the "mod"/"edit"/"prefs"/"flair menu.

For posts, it adds a link to the comment history/flag history. It also adds a link to the revhistory for posts which don't have a direct link (from the "last edited by").

[image]