# Feature request: Better support for copying code from question or answers

Tags: feature-request, code-example

Often I'd like to compile code from tex.stackexchange or other sites to my machine and play around a bit with it. There are so many great answers here; there is so much great code in stack overflow, emacs beta, askubuntu and so on.

But copying code from the website isn't really supported, at least it could be easier.

Can we get a new menu item "in" the "right-click-menu": if the mouse points to a code area, the right-click-menu offers "copy this code" ?!

Comment: Have a look at [Useful StackApps and other User Scripts for TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2475) for many useful stuff.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you, but there is no such app or script, as far as I can see.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/821/easy-way-to-copy-code-block/891#891 But it seems the link is down :-(

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/2553/select-code-block-buttons-script

Comment: Original [meta.se] request: [Shortcut or button for copying posted code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625/168244)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to the comment of Werner, I read the discussion about missing support for copying. There were unnamed security concerns. Thinking about it and not being an IT guy, a function to copy code (which is not LaTeX) to a readers clipboard doesn't sound like a horrible threat, but however, you can obviously do something evil with it, especially if the code copied isn't the code which is displayed.

Thanks to the link provided by percusse I copied the script behind the link, installed the greasemonkey addon to firefox, imported the script there and now can copy without scrolling. But I limited it to tex.stackexchange.com.

Thank you very much.

(And I thought I had a good idea. Sigh. Once in a lifetime.)

Comment: @Speravir OK, done: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6185/4736