# What is the guideline about using code backticks?

Tags: discussion, policy, markdown

I noticed that using inline code tags (`code`) is commonly use for names of packages or software (among other uses).

But we could consider a name of a software (for example) is not code... Certain kind of uses of code is just a replacement for quotations marks...

What is the general guideline to use inline code?

Comment: See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/official-capitalizations-of-words-from-the-tex-world: with a few exceptions package/class names are marked as code. (We don't have the serif/sanserif distinction available we'd use in for example `ltxdoc` files.)

Comment: Off-Topic: You can use the [main Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) for any _Quick and Short_ Q's also.

Comment: @texenthusiast It could be useful to have a topic about this question for users who ask themselves the same question.

Comment: @ppr no worries,it was just a hint or another option. Yes asking Q is very important finally.

Comment: Title is missing important information.  "Using code backticks *for package names*" would be better.

Comment: @BenVoigt My question was about when we should use (or not) code tag. It was not only about the package names case. But feel free to modify.

Comment: @ppr: As written, your question is about code tags for names of software, especially including TeX packages.  If that's not what you intended to ask, edit the question.  (But right now it's a very nice question with addressable scope, just without a matching title.)

Comment: @BenVoigt better ?

Comment: It matches the title better, but now it is broad and borderline unanswerable.  And likely to lead to a *policy* that doesn't provide specific guidance for any particular case, only some overarching expression of desirability.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not really. I think now it's quite a Meta question.

Comment: @ppr: for a clear, specific title, how about “Guideline: using code backticks for names of packages/software?”  (Or “…packages, software, etc.” if you want to keep the potential scope more general — though consensus seems to be that the more specific version is a better question.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no formal policy since, of course, you can't *force* people to use it.

With many people familiar with this *habit*, most packages/classes are written using `<code>`. And, if not, they may be edited to "conform" to this.

One advantage of using an alternative `<code>`-markdown is that it clearly highlights when you're using a package rather than just mentioning something. For example,

> I use `algorithm` and...

tells me that the OP is using either an `algorithm` environment (perhaps from [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)), or the [`algorithm` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), which provides an `algorithm` environment, as opposed to some algorithm they downloaded from the InterWebz...

<sub>The context here is somewhat superficial, but I hope it relays the message.</sub>

Comment: Backticks can get ugly, though, when lots of packages get cited.  (On SU I had an answer where someone thought all the commands should be in backticks, resulting in quite jarring rendering in my browser - http://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-which-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use/113994#113994)

Answer (score 9):

This is a little splitting the hair for my understanding. IF we force this I'm the first one who will stop using backticks :P We shouldn't have policies on such stuff because they are aids not rules.

But at least we can embed some use into this pedantry if the backticked thing is a package name. We have the amazing tool of Martin Scharrer described here; [User script for CTAN Package and TeXDoc.net buttons](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/user-script-for-ctan-package-and-texdoc-net-buttons) which when certain text is selected it converts into a CTAN or again our amazing Stefan Kottwitz and Paulo Cereda brewed TeXDoc server URLs.

[`For`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/For) [`example`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/example)  [`these`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/these) [`are`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/are) [`all`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/all) [`wrong`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/wrong) [`uses`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/uses) [`of`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/of) [`it`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/it).

Comment: I missed the fact that Martin is amazing too :)

Comment: In my mind, my question was more asking a guideline than a strict rule. If you wonder when using inline code, then, you will have the answer (for package it's ok, ...).

Comment: @ppr `policy` is a strong word

Comment: Yes. I'm no English native speaker which probably explain that.

Answer (score 8):

Does the package name have to be typed exactly so in the preamble or you get an error?  It won't work if you use a synonym, different capitalization, or hyphenate?  Why then, it really IS code after all, just a very small excerpt.

Comment: Good point. But examples such as `LaTeX` is not code...

Comment: It is code just as much as any other markup language.  Oh you mean the word *LaTeX*?  No it isn't, but `\LaTeX` is.  And so are `pdflatex` and `texify` (commands to be entered into a shell are code).

Comment: We agree, LaTeX shouldn't be codified (`\latex` should). But the common use is to use code for LaTeX...

Comment: [The correct spelling of the command is `\LaTeX`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125926/1750).  If you lose exact spelling that can be used in a document, you're no longer dealing with code, which is the main point my answer is intended to convey.  Also `latex` should be set as code if you're talking specifically about the command that performs typesetting.

Comment: @ppr Can you point to some examples where people have used `LaTeX` and not LaTeX?  I certainly don't think that the former is "common use".